# Gizmo culled depth doesn't take effect when mouse is hovered on it

Tags: python, add-on, development, gizmo

I have created a `GizmoGroup` with the option `DEPTH_3D` enabled, which, according to the docs, "Supports culled depth by other objects in the view." This works great until I move my mouse cursor over the Gizmo which causes it to appear in front of all objects. This only happens if I have draw_select defined. However, it seems that I need draw_select defined to listen for click events. Is this an intentional feature? Is there any way to disable this behavior?

Here is what I mean:
[image: Mouse moves over Gizmo and culling gets disabled]

To reproduce what I have, just run this script in an empty blend file. It will create all the necessary objects.

```py
import bpy
import math
from mathutils import Vector
from typing import Optional


class DiscGizmo(bpy.types.Gizmo):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_GT_bound_disc"
    
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linked_object: Optional[bpy.types.Object] = None

    def draw(self, context):
        self.draw_select(context, None)

    def draw_select(self, context, select_id):
        if self.linked_object.hide_get():
            return
      
        self.color = 0, 0, 1
        self.alpha = 0.5
        self.color_highlight = self.color
        self.alpha_highlight = self.alpha

        self.draw_custom_shape(
            self.mesh, matrix=self.linked_object.matrix_world, select_id=select_id)

    def generate_mesh(self, obj: bpy.types.Object):
        """Generate ``self.mesh`` and ``self.wireframe_mesh``"""
        self.linked_object = obj

        radius = 0.5
        height = 0.5
        segments = 32

        verts = self.generate_verts(radius, height, segments)
        tris = self.generate_tris(verts)

        self.mesh = self.new_custom_shape("TRIS", tris)

    @staticmethod
    def generate_verts(radius: float, height: float, segments: int = 16):
        vertices: list[Vector] = []

        for i in range(segments):
            angle = (2 * math.pi) * (i / segments)

            # Oriented on the y-z plane
            y = math.cos(angle) * radius
            z = math.sin(angle) * radius

            top_vertex = Vector((height / 2, y, z))
            bottom_vertex = Vector((-height / 2, y, z))

            vertices.append(top_vertex)
            vertices.append(bottom_vertex)

        return vertices

    @staticmethod
    def generate_tris(vertices: list[Vector]):
        # Two triangles per face
        num_tris = len(vertices)
        tris: list[Vector] = []

        # Side faces
        for i in range(num_tris):
            for j in range(3):
                vert_ind = i + j

                # Wrap back around to beginning of verts list if end is reached
                if i + j >= len(vertices):
                    vert_ind = (i + j) % len(vertices)

                tris.append(vertices[vert_ind])

        # Top faces
        for i in range(num_tris):
            if i + 2 < len(vertices):
                neighbor = vertices[i + 2]
            else:
                neighbor = vertices[(i + 2) % len(vertices)]

            tris.append(vertices[i])
            tris.append(neighbor)
            tris.append(Vector((vertices[i].x, 0, 0)))

        return tris

class BoundGizmoGroup(bpy.types.GizmoGroup):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_GGT_Bounds"
    bl_label = "Bound Shapes"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "WINDOW"
    bl_options = {"3D", "PERSISTENT", "DEPTH_3D"}

    def setup(self, context):
        for obj in context.view_layer.objects:
            if obj.hide_get():
                continue
            
            if obj.name == "bound_disc":
                gz = self.gizmos.new(DiscGizmo.bl_idname)
                gz.use_draw_modal = True
                gz.generate_mesh(obj)

bpy.utils.register_class(BoundGizmoGroup)
bpy.utils.register_class(DiscGizmo)

#Add test objects
if "bound_disc" not in bpy.data.objects:
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new("bound_disc", object_data=None)
    obj.empty_display_size = 0.0001
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)

if "Suzanne" not in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_monkey_add()
```

**Some context if interested**:

I'm trying to create Gizmos that represent collision volumes for a import/exporter. In the addon, every object has a bound type property that the GizmoGroup will check for. Depending on the bound type, it will create a Gizmo representing that primitive collision volume based off some properties defined in the addon (i.e obj.bound_radius, obj.bound_height, etc). I excluded that stuff though to produce a more minimal example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like depth is not fully supported atm. From the [source code](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/72aeee96acc8c81b41be0e89687664f28669d7c0/source/blender/windowmanager/gizmo/intern/wm_gizmo_map.c#L448), it appears that culling is disabled when the object is highlighted:

```c
/* Weak! since we don't 100% support depth yet (select ignores depth)
* always show highlighted. */
if (is_depth && (gz->state & WM_GIZMO_STATE_HIGHLIGHT)) {
    is_depth = false;
}
```

Hopefully this will be changed soon.